# Copying files from one directory to another with rules in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I want to copy files from one directory to another in java but I have the following situation:

- The source directory might have an arbitrary depth
- I have a set of rules for the copy, for example:

  - "Copy all the files that end in *.dll"
  - "Copy a subdirectory and all contents"
  - "Copy only this specific file"
- These rules are configurable, so that means that they will be read from some file

Looking at this particular problem, it seems like the copy command in Ant does what I need, but I can't use ANT for this project, so I wonder if there is something out there that would allow me to do what ANT does in a normal java program

I took a look at Apache Commons, but the FileUtils method doesn't seem to contain a method to pass "filters"

I could implement this from scratch using the File class and some FilenameFilters, but I am sure someone had this problem before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Coming up with a syntax for your rules, and parsing that syntax, is much more difficult than doing the file copies.  You could use the Ant syntax for file filtering.

Comment: I would definitively like to use the Ant Syntax, the problem is that I can not use Ant for this application.

Comment: The Ant syntax is XML.  You can use any Java XML parser to get the information you need into an internal Java format you can use.